How to run scipy.optimize.minimize with L-BFGS-B for maxiter (completely)
I want to run the below code for maxiter = 20001. I don't want it to stop by some default criteria.
results = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=get_loss_and_grads,
    x0=params,
    jac=True,
    method='L-BFGS-B',
    options={'maxiter': 20001, 'disp': True, 'ftol': 0.0, 'gtol': 0.0, 'maxcor': 50},
    callback=PrintLossCallback(print_freq=100)
)

Currently, it is stopped at approx. 2500 iterations but I want it to run for a full 20001 iterations. How to do that? Below is the full code:
def get_loss_and_grads(params):
    shapes = [w.shape for w in model.get_weights()]
    split_params = np.split(params, np.cumsum([np.prod(shape) for shape in shapes[:-1]]))
    weights = [tf.Variable(param.reshape(shape)) for param, shape in zip(split_params, shapes)]
    model.set_weights(weights)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = combined_loss(X_train_tf[:, 0:1], X_train_tf[:, 1:2], x_init_tf, t_init_tf, u_initial_tf, x_bc_tf, t_bc_tf)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    flattened_gradients = np.concatenate([grad.numpy().flatten() for grad in gradients])
    return loss.numpy().astype(np.float64), flattened_gradients

X_train_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train.astype(np.float32))
x_init_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_init.astype(np.float32))
t_init_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(t_init.astype(np.float32))
u_initial_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(u_initial.astype(np.float32))
x_bc_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_bc.astype(np.float32))
t_bc_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(t_bc.astype(np.float32))


shapes = [w.shape for w in model.get_weights()]
params = np.concatenate([w.flatten() for w in model.get_weights()])

class PrintLossCallback:
    def __init__(self, print_freq=100):
        self.print_freq = print_freq
        self.iteration = 0

    def __call__(self, xk):
        self.iteration += 1
        if self.iteration % self.print_freq == 0:
            loss, _ = get_loss_and_grads(xk)
            print(f"Iteration {self.iteration}, Loss: {loss}")

start_time = time.time()


results = scipy.optimize.minimize(
    fun=get_loss_and_grads,
    x0=params,
    jac=True,
    method='L-BFGS-B',
    options={'maxiter': 20001, 'disp': True, 'ftol': 0.0, 'gtol': 0.0, 'maxcor': 50},
    callback=PrintLossCallback(print_freq=100)
)

optimized_params = results.x
split_params = np.split(optimized_params, np.cumsum([np.prod(shape) for shape in shapes[:-1]]))
model.set_weights([param.reshape(shape) for param, shape in zip(split_params, shapes)])

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
elapsed_minutes = elapsed_time / 60.0  # Convert seconds to minutes

print(f"Execution time: {elapsed_minutes:.2f} minutes")

I tried to set 'ftol': 0.0, 'gtol': 0.0, and maxiter to a large number like 200001 but all in vain.

Why did the optimization stop? Did it say it was because it exceed a certain number of steps or did you get an error message?

I guess it stopped because of ftol and gtol. Please check this for more details.
It didn't give any error.

Did it say the optimization converged? You can check result.success to see if it thought the optimization actually converged and result.message would describe why the optimization ended.

Thank you for the guide—the results. Success gives True and results. Message gives CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH. What does this mean? And, what should I do next to run my code for 20001 iterations?

With these:
options={'maxiter': 20001, 'disp': True, 'ftol': 1e-12, 'gtol': 1e-12,'maxcor': 50}
I got this
results.success: False
results.message: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH

Look at the docs of this particular Script algorithm and set all the tolerances to extremely low values, e.g. 1e-14. Beware that if they are too low, they might be replaced by larger ones. The goal here is to make it impossible to satisfy the convergence criteria. But basically,  the last few thousands iterations will be most likely the solution circling around the exact solution at a very small radius...

Perhaps running the standalone BFGS function outside of the minimize wrapper will allow for greater control over its behavior https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b

REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH It looks like this is saying it reached a point where the reduction in your function REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_ was right around machine precision. This means the change in the function value was so small between iterations that it was essentially just noise, so continuing the optimization further couldn't produce anymore tangible improvement. ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH is less specific, but the line search is how L-BFGS determines its next step, so it suggests again that very small differences made it impossible to find a reasonable step to take.

@Tyberius The default termination criteria is much larger than machine precision. The _FACTR variable is calculated here as ftol / np.finfo(float).eps. Expanding that out, it is REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=ftol*EPSMCH/EPSMCH, which simplifies to REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=ftol. The variable ftol defaults to 2.22e-09, which is much bigger than machine precision. So specifying a smaller ftol as a solver option is one way to make the optimizer look for a closer point.

I am trying to replicate this work where author has trained the model for 20000 iterations. I used L-BFGS from fmin_l_bfgs_b & from minimize wrapper but they stopped early within 1500 iterations. I also tried L-BFGS-B from tensorflow_probability. However, tfp does not support callback so I cannot print out number of iterations, hence cannot say whether it ran for full iterations or stopped early. I have set tolerance=1e-12 and stopping_condition=None for tfp.

Recompiling some comments, iterative algorithms have two stopping criteria: optimistic and pessimistic. The number of iterations is a pessimistic criterion and is supposed to act when the optimistic (convergence) is not reached.
You do not provide a minimum working example to test your code. But I am guessing that your function is too simple to need the number of iterations you want. And, as mentioned in the comments, at some point your iterations might start oscillating around a local minimum.
I managed to set up some parameters for the minimization of the Rosenbrock function that require 20001 iterations. Notice that I needed to increase the maximum number of function evaluations as well. Also, see that I am using the L-BFGS-B function directly instead of the wrapper provided in minimize.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import rosen, rosen_der, fmin_l_bfgs_b as lbfgs


ndim = 100000
x0 = np.random.uniform(-5.0, 5.0, ndim)
x_opt, f_opt, info = lbfgs(rosen, x0, fprime=rosen_der, maxiter=20001,
                           maxfun=50001, pgtol=1e-14, factr=10)


I am also trying to solve non-convex hyperbolic PDE. Actually, I am trying to replicate this work where author have trained model for 20000 iterations with L-BFGS-B. I used fmin_l_bfgs_b directly but it also stopped early within 1500 iterations. I also tried L-BFGS-B from tensorflow_probability but it also stopped early.
